How to reveal class/styles per component such as color and font used in Storybook
I am not a developer, im a designer. My problem is i'm trying to figure out how to reveal more information in Storybook stories so as a Designer I can check content without having to browser inspect and sift through html.
Things like what color is used in a background of a button, what font-family is used etc. little things that would make my life of checking Storybook for consistency with Figma a lot easier that would be good to see within storybook - the code expand doesn't seem to help.
Word from my developer who tried to get it working:
"added theme and font class dropdowns on the top. They are added to the root element and they were previously hardcoded. However in terms of inspecting colour/font each element can have specific class/styles assigned and I can't think of anything else than checking it in the dev tools."
I'm just trying to at least in some way reveal the contents of the component, if a design token is used, its name and hex code for colours, or font-family for text. Outline thickness is another one that would be helpful.
Heres what we found, but doesn't work anymore, though would be ideal:
https://storybook.js.org/addons/display-element-css

There are chrome extensions which could help you with these tasks.
CSS Peeper - Gives mostly all relevant style info for an element. see this intro video, if required
WhatFont - mostly gives you info about the font used in a section. doesn't show background color.
You can also search for more such extensions at https://chromewebstore.google.com/

Thanks for the suggestion I'll take a look at extensions.
Those two though, do not work with Storybook.

don't see a reason why it would not work. maybe the demo videos should help.
